# Translate Animation stuck the code game

Tags: java, android, animation, translate-animation, start-activity

I have serious problem in my game which I'm developing right now in android studio. The problem is as follow:

I have 2 activities, one the activity of the game, and the other is the activity of the menu.

When the activity of the menu is created, I have translate animation which starting right in the onResume() method of the activity. This is the animation:

```
TranslateAnimation outAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, w, 0f, 0f);
    outAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    outAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    outAnim.setDuration(10000);
    mBackGround1.startAnimation(outAnim);
```

The problem happens when I go from the game activity to the menu activity( using startActivity(new Intent(...) ), and then ***the game activity does not get closed until the animation is finished !! ( It supposed to get closed because I used startActivity Method) e.g, the onPause() method of the activity is called, but the onStop() method is not called !! It is called only after the first animation repeat is finished, meaning after 10 sec.***

And this is causing me a lot of problems because if the user wants to go back to the activity of the game, while it is not closed, the lifecycle is getting crazy, and I cant understand nothing.

So my question is:

Why does the animation block,stop, and make the code "stuck" for 10 sec ? how can I make the animation to not stuck the code, if its even possible ?

More info:

When I disable the code of the animation, the onStop() method is getting called right after the game activity is closed, which confirm to me that the animation is the problem.

Comment: What does the user do in order to go back? Press the BACK button?

Comment: He clicks on certain point in the screen, which is the "home" button of my game. Its the back button of the game, not the phone. Then when he clicks, I'm using startActivity.